# How can I avoid having to put 0s into the NULL fields to get a correct query calculation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets question, which I have not been able to figure out yet with Google-Fu and RTFM:

Take the following spreadsheet as an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IvMVaUdUDfYOoKyG0Uwd2n0M1mLjOTE5yZQ9K2R3q2M/edit?usp=sharing

In case the sheet gets lost in time, I am going to post its contents here:

Sheet1:

| foo | withdrawal | deposit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 4 | 10 |
| D | 10 |  |
| E | 10 | 4 |

As you see here, the `withdrawal` field for the D value being `foo` is empty, i.e. null

Sheet2:

| foo | balance |
| --- | --- |
| C | =INDEX(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:C}, "SELECT SUM(Col3) - SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '"&A2&"'"), 2) |
| D | =INDEX(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:C}, "SELECT SUM(Col3) - SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '"&A3&"'"), 2) |
| E | =INDEX(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:C}, "SELECT SUM(Col3) - SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = '"&A4&"'"), 2) |

The result is

| foo | balance |
| --- | --- |
| C | 6 |
| D |  |
| E | -6 |

As you see, the `balance` field for the category `D` is null, although it should be -10.

The fix for that is to put a `0` into the deposit field in Sheet1 explicitly.

In my example, I get that data using a csv-export, and fields are generally empty and not 0, and it is cumbersome to add the 0 there. Is there a way to have something like `COALESCE` in that sum there (like in SQL)?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like something quite a bit simpler would avoid the problem:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!C:C-Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2)
```

for cell B2.

Comment: Hmmm... I wasn't aware of this function, and I will give it a try

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oHflpaw01gJGM1MjFeH0LM4vSd1BDwWesGkxsnFESIk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add this in cell `A1` of Sheet2 instead of all the Query:

```
=arrayformula({Sheet1!A1,"balance";if(Sheet1!A2:A<>"",{Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B},)})
```

Obviously ensure cells `Sheet2!A2:A` and `Sheet2!B1:B` are empty.

If you have duplicate values of foo, try:

```
=arrayformula(query({Sheet1!A1,"balance";if(Sheet1!A2:A<>"",{Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!C2:C-Sheet1!B2:B},)},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'balance'",1))
```

A better option for a single-cell formula, referencing multiple sheets would be:

```
=arrayformula(query(
{Sheet1!A:A,n(Sheet1!B:C);Sheet2!A2:A,n(Sheet2!B2:C);Sheet3!A2:A,n(Sheet3!B2:C)},
"select Col1,sum(Col3)-sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col3)-sum(Col2) 'balance' ",1))
```

Comment: Ah, since I tried to do a minimal example that is I guess not entirely clear; I am actually pulling from many spreadsheets.

Comment: Amended solution.